# Static code on Solaris?

Tags: static-libraries, solaris-10

#### Question:

- Why were static libraries `/usr/lib/*.a` dropped from **Solaris 10**?
- So it is **NOT** possible to generate statically-linked object?

  - Dynamically-linked compilation, is the only option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can still create your own *.a libraries and link to them, but the system libraries will always be dynamically linked.

See: [this post from blogs.oracle.com](https://blogs.oracle.com/quenelle/entry/solaris_10_ack_where_did)

Answer (score 2):

If you pass the right flags to the linker, then you can create a static library or application. However, why would you want to? Static libraries are a pain to provide fixes for.

Answer (score 1):

It's a wise decision. The static linking idea does not really work well. Thats why LSB (Linux Standard Base) Project also forbids static linking. Compatibility moved away from system calls to a higher level in the last two decades.

Answer (score 0):

Can't say I've ever gone looking for them, but did you check the "additional options" (or whatever they call it) CD/DVD?  I remember it had other random "missing" things...

Comment: @Brian, Sun has removed all support for statically linked system libraries in Solaris 10, it's not an installation issue.

Comment: Pedantically, it's more that Solaris 10 and later are not shipped with staticly linked binaries. You can still create them if you want.